# Ruby: Why does this work the way it does?

Tags: ruby

In this code:

```
class A
  @@a = 0
  def initialize
      @@a = @@a + 1
  end

  def to_s
    @@a
  end
end

a = A.new
p a
b = A.new
p b
```

The output is 1 and 2. But if I remove the `def initialize ... end` and have `@@a = @@a + 1` immediately after `@@a = 0` on the third line, then the output is 1 and 1. I know that after initializing an object, the `initialize` method executes as the first method after calling `A.new`, but I'm not really sure how the class variable `@@a` is being handled.

Why doesn't the `@@a` variable auto-increment when I have `@@a = @@a + 1` not wrapped inside the `initialize` method? I mean, it makes sense for it to increment, because after you call `A.new`, `@@a = 0`, and `@@a = @@a + 1` => 1 = 0 + 1. Then for `b = A.new`, you repeat and get 2. This doesn't happen for some reason and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the code in body of the class is executed once - when class is loaded. So `@@a` class variable increments only once.

On the other hand, the code in `initialize` method runs every time you call `A.new`.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby is executing your file from top to bottom.

In the version with the `initialize` function, Ruby (roughly speaking):

1. Enters the class definition
2. Defines the class variable `@@a`, and assigns it 0
3. Defines the `initialize` function and the `to_s` function
4. Creates a new `A`, running `initialize` and incrementing `@@a` to 1
5. Creates a new `A`, running `initialize` and incrementing `@@a` to 2

In the version with the `@@a` not in a function:

1. Enters the class definition
2. Defines the class variable `@@a`, and assigns it 0
3. Increments the class variable `@@a` to 1
4. Defines the `to_s` function
5. Creates a new `A`, running no initializer
6. Creates a new `A`, running no initializer

So `@@a` is only incremented *once* - when Ruby executes the code in the class definition.